# Excel vba list box multi column multi row from 14 text boxes

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have user form with 14 text boxes , 2 command buttons " next " , " Post " and 1 list box

I need code to get the data from the 14 text boxes to the list box , again when the user enter new data and press next this data added to second row in the list box , gain , again

finally when he press post all data move to work sheet " Database"

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim arr1, i As Long
Dim arr2(0 To 0, 0 To 13)
arr1 = Array(TB10, TB10, TB0, tb1, cb1, cb2, tb5, tb4, TB10, TB10, TB10,  tb6, tb7, tb8)
For i = 0 To UBound(arr1)
    arr2(0, i) = arr1(i)
Next i
ListBox1.List = arr2

End Sub
```

but this code is only add one time data to list box , i need to add more rows ♥

Comment: *"To get the data from the 14 text boxes to the list box "* you should correct the syntax of the `.List` assignment to `... = Me.Controls(arr1(i)).Value` to get the controls' value; `Me` is just a placeholder for the current Userform instance. - BTW Why don't you use one single array? You can rewrite data assigning `.List` to a defined range as a whole - but there are number of example codes at SO - try to find by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***"...Need to add more rows"***

Normally you would assign a complete(d) data set to the `.List` property of your `ListBox1` (you chose to Name it `arr2`).

As you want to increase the number of contained element rows with each `CommandButton1_Click()` event and preserve all existing data, theoretically you'd need increment the 1st dimension of a 2-dimensional array - but that's not possible using `ReDim Preserve`.

To overcome this issue, simply reverse dimensions of `arr2` thus defining your 14 column values in its first dimension and the "row" dimension as 2nd one. A listbox control offers a `.Column` property which you can use instead of the usual `.List` property to write the whole data set back (without need to care of the intentionally transposed rows & columns).

**Note**

As you changed code in OP, I assume `tb0`, `tb1`, ... correspond to enumerated TextBox controls. (*Please change the somewhat bizarre order in the controls Array `arr1` to your needs.*)

**Example code**

```
Option Explicit                         ' declaration head of userform code module
Dim arr2()                              ' make arr2 values disponible for each CommandButton1_Click event

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' declare/assign variables
  Dim arr1(), i As Long, nxt As Long
  arr1 = Array(tb0, tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4, tb5, tb6, tb7, tb8, tb9, tb10, tb11, tb12, tb13) ' <~~ Change order to your needs
' define index of next row in listbox
  nxt = Me.ListBox1.ListCount  ' ListCount automatically counts upper bound + 1
' a) you can only increment an array's last dimension, so ...
' b) redefine arr2 with new elements in its 2nd dimension
  ReDim Preserve arr2(0 To UBound(arr1), 0 To nxt)
' assign textbox and combobox values to arr2
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr1)
      arr2(i, nxt) = arr1(i)
  Next i
' reassign arr2 to the listboxes .Column property (instead of the .List property)
  ListBox1.Column = arr2
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Layout()
  With Me.ListBox1
       .ColumnCount = 14                                            ' define column count
       .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50"  ' <~~ change to your needs
  '    .Width = 50 * .ColumnCount + 16
  End With
End Sub
```

Allow me a remark: I think this answers your original question. You'll find enough examples how to move data back to a worksheet reading StackOverflow site, but this would need to formulate a new question with code showing what you've tried so far - see  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks alot for your help , it solve my problem and its working , now how can i move the data back to the work sheet ? i will search on StackOverflow site and i will make a new question with my achievement . really thanks for your support